# Selecting an item from pop-up menu

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm trying to make an application that will test some features of an existing app and I wanted it not to be window-size dependent and not to require focusing the window or etc.

I've already figured out how to get window handles for different controls in the tested app so I can click buttons, enter text to textboxes etc. with Send/Post Message but still got a few unsolved problems.

The first is selecting an item from a pop-up menu that can be triggered by button click (TAdvGlowMenuButton class) or right click somewhere- I can't even see any messages related to it in Spy++ so I have no idea how to do it, is it possible to select an item by name? as I don't have it's id

The second thing is clicking next to something, for example 10 pixels to the right of a button.
I have the button handle so I can get it's size and it's parent but I still don't know how to get it's position inside the parent - any ideas?:)

And also a quick one but I don't believe it is possible - can I somehow get position of a label in the tested app? I can't even see it in Spy++ .

I hope you can help me to find it out ;)

Edit: I forgot about the most important thing:P , I'd like to achieve it with Send/Post Message if only it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to abandon the message sending/posting model altogether and instead use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684007.aspx). Automated testing tools is exactly what the UI Automation APIs were designed for, and they are much more capable than SendMessage/PostMessage.

Yes, I realize that this is exactly the opposite of the answer you were looking for. But you will have no end of trouble getting messages to do what you want. A fair number of them rely on the application having the focus, and it is completely reasonable for your code to make this assumption when you receive e.g. a `WM_KEYDOWN` message. A testing tool should not flag that as a bug.

I notice you've tagged this question with the C# and .NET tags. In that case, you may be interested to learn that the UI Automation APIs have been [wrapped in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: I see, I think it'd be a good idea to move to Automation but can I get it working with controls from TMS/devexpress? TAdvGlowButton, TComboBox, TdxMaskEdit etc ?

Comment: @Andrzej Well, the whole point of UI Automation is that the underlying implementation of the control does not matter. It is much more likely to work with custom controls than sending them messages intended for the native Windows controls. Most custom controls don't properly handle these messages. Anyway, if DevExpress controls don't work with UI Automation, that's a serious bug with those controls. Another good reason not to use custom controls, they are too often broken and hacked together. The native Windows controls work quite well. I recommend applying for a refund.